# How can I XML Serialize an object that is the base class and has 4 derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

So this is my base class:

```
[Serializable]

    public class Clienti:IComparable
    {

        public String Nume { get; set; }
        public String Prenume { get; set; }
        public String Adresa { get; set; }
        public long CNP { get; set; }
        public String SerieBuletin { get; set; }
        public String DataNasterii { get; set; }
        public String Telefon { get; set; }
        public List<Asigurari> listaAsigurari { get; set; }
    }
```

The class that is the List in Clienti is this one:

```
 [Serializable]
    public abstract class Asigurari
    {
        //atribute cu AutoProperties
        public String denumireBun { get; set; }
        public String numeAsigurator { get; set; }
        public String locatieBun { get; set; }
        public float sumaAsigurare { get; set; }
        public String dataPolitaInceput { get; set; }
        public String dataPolitaSfarsit { get; set; }
        public String tipAsigurare { get; set; }
    }
```

and practically this one is the base clase for the other 4 classes:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Automobil:Asigurari
    {
        public String marca { get; set; }
        public String model { get; set; }
        public String numarImatriculare { get; set; }
        public String serieSasiu { get; set; }
        public int capacitateCilindrica { get; set; }
        public int numarLocuri { get; set; }
        public int masaMaximaAdmisa { get; set; }
     }

    [Serializable]
    public class AlteBunuri:Asigurari
    {
        public String detaliiBun { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]

    public class Locuinta:Asigurari
    {
        public String Adresa { get; set; }
        public tipLocuinta tip { get; set; }
        public int numarNiveluri { get; set; }
        public float suprafataTotala { get; set; }
        public float suprafataUtilizabila { get; set; }
        public int numarCamere { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]

    public class Viata:Asigurari
    {
        public int varsta { get; set; }
        public String grupaSangvina { get; set; }
        public float inaltime { get; set; }
        public float greutate { get; set; }
        public Gen gen { get; set; }
        public StareCivila stareCivila { get; set; }

     }
```

every class of these 4 has contructor with params, and without.

And my code for XML Serialise and Deserialize is this :

```
private void xMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Clienti>),new Type[] { typeof(Asigurari)});

            System.IO.FileStream fs = File.Create("lista.xml");
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, listaClienti);

            fs.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Serializare cu succes in lista.xml");
        }

        private void coleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Clienti>));

            try
            {
                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("lista.xml");
                listaClienti = xml.Deserialize(fs) as List<Clienti>;

                fs.Close();
                populareLV();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

and I get this error:
[image]

Sorry for the long post or if I did not explain it so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception message says, you need to let the base class know of derived types like

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Automobil))]
public abstract class Asigurari
{
    //atribute cu AutoProperties
    public String denumireBun { get; set; }
    public String numeAsigurator { get; set; }
    public String locatieBun { get; set; }
    public float sumaAsigurare { get; set; }
    public String dataPolitaInceput { get; set; }
    public String dataPolitaSfarsit { get; set; }
    public String tipAsigurare { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And if I would want to use a Json Serializer? same problem, the abstract class

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XmlIncludeAttribute` when you call the `Serialize` or `Deserialize` method of the `XmlSerializer` class.

You should specify the `[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedType1), XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedType2)...]` attributes on the base class

Comment: And  this one I use it in the base class where I typed [Serializable]

Comment: @VictorMitoi Yes, you should use that in the base class